# I'm starting to learn to use JFrame and JPanel. Why is my code not working?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm starting to learn to use JFrame and JPanel. Why is my code not working?
For some reason when I run it a JFrame does open but there is no grid layout and no borders.

main:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ht {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frame = new screen();
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The screen Class:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class screen extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */

private cell[][] arr = new cell[3][3];

public screen()
{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));



    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            panel.add(arr[i][j] = new cell());
        }
    }



    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
}

public class cell extends JPanel{

    private String type1;

    public cell()
    {
        type1 = "white";
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red,1));
    }
}
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You create your JPanel, panel, but add it to nothing. You should add it to your JFrame for it to show.

```
// class name should start with an upper case letter.
public class Screen extends JFrame {

    // class name should start with an upper case letter.
    private Cell[][] arr = new Cell[3][3];

    public Screen() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                panel.add(arr[i][j] = new Cell());
            }
        }

        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));


        add(panel);  // ***** add panel to the JFrame *****
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3672173: you're welcome.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I made the answer a Swing wiki since it seemed a trivial problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: the quality of the question itself is low, because it is a trivial problem, and so I doubt that it will be of much help to future visitors.